# how to get the preloaded services?

Tags: boot, package-management, software-center, plugins

I installed the Ubuntu 14.04 by CD , at that time i had no internet connection due to that i am not able to get all the built-in packages. Some of the problems arises like, plug ins required for playing mp3, mp4 formats and so on, 
    how to get all those packages. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well download from someone else's computer and do it but still, here is the answer:

When Installing Ubuntu, it uses the DVD to load Ubuntu and same for the packages. When Installing you get an option to update from the internet, do not select that. Remember your **PASSWORD**

Install as usual and after installation reboot but **without removing the DVD**

Now go in your terminal and type this

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It will ask for your password

It is the file where is installation sources is listed, it will look like

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Alpha amd64 (20150228)]/ vivid main $

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
```

Your's will be different

Now the first line will allow the system to use your CD as a software repository, so now uncomment it and it should now look like

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Alpha amd64 (20150228)]/ vivid main $

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
```

This is the important line (Only...)

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Alpha amd64 (20150228)]/ vivid main $
```

Then Press Ctrl + X then press Shift + Y and Press Enter

This is done, now in your normal terminal type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This updates the repository, now you need to enter your password as auth, you will see a long list.

Then you may install only some packages not all.